# Instapy Failed to Like ----- Error media = post_page[0]["shortcode_media"] instapy-0.6.14

Tags: python, instagram, instapy

I am using instapy-0.6.14

code:

```
from instapy import InstaPy

import random
from instapy import InstaPy
from instapy import smart_run

#login credentials
insta_username = '****'
insta_password = '****'

#login session
session = InstaPy(username=insta_username, password=insta_password)
session.login()

session.like_by_tags(["#carz"], amount=5)
```

**getting below error**

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Study\Python_Automation\Insta_Commentor\quickstart.py", line 56, in
session.like_by_tags(my_hashtags, amount=90, media=None)
File "C:\Users\sonu3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\instapy\instapy.py", line 1977, in like_by_tags
inappropriate, user_name, is_video, reason, scope = check_link(
File "C:\Users\sonu3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\instapy\like_util.py", line 618, in check_link
media = post_page[0]["shortcode_media"]
KeyError: 0

Comment: Up, I've just got this error and could figure this out yet. Have you already solved it?

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me:
https://github.com/InstaPy/InstaPy/issues/6472

---

```
Line 619 etc. replaced with:
logger.info("post_page: {}".format(post_page))
media = post_page ['items'] [0]
is_video = media ["is_unified_video"]
user_name = media ["user"] ["username"]
image_text = media ["caption"] ["text"]
owner_comments = ""
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).